# MySQL Order By Rand() gives 1 result not 24

Tags: php, mysql, random

I want to display 24 unique id's but he is only giving me 1:
This is my php

```
    <?php $sql = "SELECT id 
                          FROM 15players 
                          ORDER BY RAND() 
                          LIMIT 24";    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());        
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['id'];         ?>
```

But if I execute this SQL in phpmyadmin,
It returns me 24 id's
So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Got the right answer!

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT id 
                      FROM 15players 
                      ORDER BY RAND() 
                      LIMIT 0,24";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo $row['id'];
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: You're only fetching one result `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` so of course you'll only get one id displayed.... iterate over the entire resultset fetching each in turn `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['id']; }`

Comment: But it's 2015 now, time to move into the world of MySQLi or PDO rather than the old, deprecated MySQL extension that won't exist in the latest PHP after November 12th

Comment: Please please please don't use `mysql_*` anymore. At least use `mysqli_*` if not PDO. http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Don't ever write `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` only returns 1 row you need to loop through the results.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D How can I get a <br> between every 'id' ?

Comment: `echo $row['id'], '<br />';` I really would suggest learning a few PHP basics

Answer (score 0):

If multiple results are fetched via a query, you need to iterate over it.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT id 
FROM 15players 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 24";    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());        
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['id'];
}         
?>
```

Also **mysql_*** is deprecated, start using PDO.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array only get one row at a time. You need to loop through all of your results.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
     echo $row['id']. '<br>';
}
```

You should be using mysqli or PDO. The mysql_ is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.